# iOS devices only visible to Xcode for a short time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

This is happening intermittently, but frequently iOS devices are connecting to my MacBook Pro (mid-2014) and then quickly disconnecting. Without any clear error or log to indicate why.

[image: iPhoneConnectsAndThenDisconnects]

**Where should I look for event logs that may help indicate what the underlying error is?** I've tried to look through console logs for system events but I haven't seen anything that jumps out.

I've gone through many of the recommended solutions for Xcode not recognizing iOS devices:

- Clean Project
- Delete `DerivedData` folder
- Restart Xcode
- Restart the Mac
- Restart the iPhone
- Reset device permissions to re-trigger the "Trust Computer" prompt
- Deleted `iOS DeviceSupport` folder
- Alternated USB ports
- Kill USB process
- Deleted and re-installed the latest version of iTunes
- Swapped out 4 different lightning cables
- Tried 5+ different iOS devices with various versions of the OS
- Went back to Xcode 8.2.1 to see if it was an issue with 8.3.1

Corporate IT reset my [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) this morning. I put in a request to have them disable [Sentinel Agent](https://sentinelone.com/) to see if that's a factor, but it's not the clear culprit since other developers are still able to connect.

Very rarely, the connection will hold and I can use the device just fine. I have yet to determine what combination of astrological events leads to that case though.

Comment: It's unclear, are you wanting to stay connected to the device? You should probably check Console.app when it happens, there has to be some logged information.

Comment: Yes I am trying to stay connected. I've looked through Console.app as it happens, but I haven't seen anything that seems to related to this. Any suggestions for event types or items to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and tried 10+ of the things you listed as well.  Even tried uninstalling a few things that could have been interfering.  As soon as I switched USB ports it worked and stayed connected.  **Turned out to be lint/dust in the USB port.**  A little duster in the port and it works like a charm. Sometimes the answer is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a disappointing solution, but IT reimaged my machine and the device connection has been stable ever since.

So if all else fails for you, start over.

**Update:**
This ultimately was narrowed down to an issue with Mobile Labs Device Bridge. Removing their launch daemons and restarting the system is the much simpler solve!